# How to get the size of a collection by mongo-go-driver

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

I need to get the size of the mongo database collection.
The project is written in golang using [mongo-go-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver).

Answer (score 5):

> I need to get the size of the mongo database collection.

You can get a variety of storage statistics of MongoDB collection using [collStats](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/collStats/#dbcmd.collStats) command. You can utilise [Database.RunCommand](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Database.RunCommand) to execute database commands with [MongoDB Go driver](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo). For example:

```
db := client.Database("databaseName")

result := db.RunCommand(context.Background(), bson.M{"collStats":"collectionname"})

var document bson.M
err = result.Decode(&document)

if err !=nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Printf("Collection size: %v Bytes\n", document["size"])
fmt.Printf("Average object size: %v Bytes\n", document["avgObjSize"])
fmt.Printf("Storage size: %v Bytes\n", document["storageSize"])
fmt.Printf("Total index size: %v Bytes\n", document["totalIndexSize"])
```

The example above only print 4 information related to your question. However there are more information returned by `collStats`, you can see more information on [Basic Stats Lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.stats/#basic-stats-lookup) example. You can also specify `scale` parameter to change the bytes to kilobytes, see [Stats Lookup with Scale](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.stats/#stats-lookup-with-scale).

Note that the example above is written with mongo-go-driver v1.1.x.

Answer (score 4):

There are two methods for checking this

The exact one with [CountDocuments](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection.CountDocuments)

```
count, err := client.Database("webshop").Collection("products").CountDocuments(context.Background(), bson.D{})
```

and estimation with [EstimatedDocumentCount](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection.EstimatedDocumentCount)

```
count, err := client.Database("webshop").Collection("products").EstimatedDocumentCount(context.Background())
```

Answer (score 0):

in mongodb

```js
db.getCollection('collection').find({}).count()
```